# How to check for various conditions and return an accumulated result in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am new to using XSLT transforms and I been into a case where I need an accumulated result by validating multiple sibling nodes. My case is as follows:

**XML File ( Example )**

```
<Person>
  <Name> Kavya </Name>
  <Gift>
    <ItemName> Photo Frame </ItemName>
    <Price> 999 </Price>
  </Gift>
  <Gift>
    <ItemName> Teddy Bear </ItemName>
    <Price> 1500 </Price>
  </Gift>
  <Gift>
    <ItemName> Flower Bouquet </ItemName>
    <Price> 1000 </Price>
  </Gift>
  <Gift>
    <ItemName> Chocolates </ItemName>
    <Price> 500 </Price>
  </Gift>
</Person>
```

**Question**

For the above document, I have to return a node with ***Gift Found*** text only when the below condition is matched,

> Name = Kavya, ItemName = Photo Frame, Price != 500

Only when the above condition is matched, I would return

```
<Result> Gift Found </Result>
```

I thought of using **for-each** to loop through items but an accumulated result using multiple nodes, I am stuck somewhere in-between.

Kindly assist.

Comment: It is not clear where you are stuck, have you written any XPath expressions and XSLT code to represent the conditions and to produce output?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the XSLT using for-each to get the desired output. But, I couldn't get it. Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: You do not need to use `xsl:for-each` if you want a boolean result. Simply check for the existence of node/s that meet the criteria.

Comment: I need to take ItemName and Price of the gifts and apply **equal to** and **not equal to** operations on it and come up with a single result. So, my question is how would i take, for example, all the ItemName in one go?

Comment: That's how XPath works. For example the expression in `<xsl:if test="Person[Name='Kavya']/Gift[ItemName='Photo Frame' and Price != 500]">` will return true if there is at least one `Gift` element that meets the stated conditions.

Comment: Do note that `</ItemFrame>` does not close `<ItemName>` and that `"Kavya"` does not equal `" Kavya "`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for your response. Since, there is some more detail to my question, I have created a new thread. Kindly assist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132681/how-to-pick-value-of-multiple-nodes-and-test-it-in-a-single-condition

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for the response. Please assist on the above.